# Live streaming using iPhone and saving the video

Tags: iphone

What technology  is used for  live  streaming of video  from iPhone  cam to a  distant  server.

I want  to show  live  streaming as well as save the  video,  once  it  gets finished.

Comment: 9 Questions and you couldn't accept an answer to one of the 8 that have an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way its being done right now is by capturing the frames as the movie is taken (right now its being  done through a screenshot private api, but now with 4.0 u can grab the frame of videos a better way, cant discuss that right now tho), then take  some number of frames, encode them using ffmpeg or some ohter encoding library, send the video chunks to your server and live stream them using the  live http streaming...thats a birdeye view of how its being done..hope it helps

Comment: Hi user338322, could you please share something on how you have got this working. I am also trying to do the similar thing.